# Checkbutton and Scale conflict

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with my Checkbutton widget. Every time I select it the slider on the scale widget above moves by itself to 1, deselecting the Checkbutton widget will set the Scale widget to 0. Both widgets are not intended to be related with each other in any way yet for some reason changing values in one of them affect the other. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how can I avoid such problems in the future?

```
    tk.Label(f7, text=("Jakość")).grid(row=3, column=0)
    self.jakosc=tk.Scale(f7, orient='horizontal', variable=jakosc)
    self.jakosc.grid(row=3, column=1)
    self.rozpinany_sweter=tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(f7, text='Rozpinany',variable=rozpinany_sweter).grid(row=4, column=1)
```

[In this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5UDf.png)
 the slider is set to 56, after checking the checkbox on the slider sets itself to 1.

EDIT: MCVE provided:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as ttk
RS=0
Q=0
class Aplikacja(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()
def create_widgets(self):
    self.jakosc=tk.Scale(root, orient='horizontal', variable=Q)
    self.jakosc.grid()
    self.rozpinany_sweter=tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=RS).grid()

root= tk.Tk()
app= Aplikacja(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The symptoms you describe suggest that both widgets are tied to the same variable, but without seeing how you define both variables it's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `variable=` parameter to Tk widgets MUST be a Tk variable (created by Tk.IntVar() or similar calls).  Your code passes Q and RS, which are ordinary Python variables; the one Tk variable you create is pointless, because you never use it anywhere.  Tk variables have a special ability not possessed by Python variables: they can have watchers attached to them, which allows widgets to automatically update themselves when the variable is modified.

The Python representation of a Tk variable is basically just the Tk name of the variable.  Both Q and RS happen to have the same value, so they're both referring to the same variable on the Tk side - that's why your scale and checkbox appear to be linked.